# Core Data store being deleted on launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-data

I have a rather odd issue i can't work out, i have a non document based application on OSX that is using Core Data as it storage mechanism.

All was fine until recently when it started nuking the core data information on launch. To my knowledge i haven't changed any of the core data methods in the intervening period.

It's driving me absolutely nuts, i can watch the store file grow as the app runs, and it stays as it is when the application quits, but as soon as a launch it the file drops in size and all the object are removed.

I think it has something to do with when the coredatamodel is initialised, but i haven't managed to pin down exactly when it's removed and in what method.

Has anyone seen this before/able to offer any pointers.

Happy to post up and code you guys might think is relevant.

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: There's nothing in Core Data that automatically deletes data stores for no reason. You're not giving enough information to guess what might be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually idiot factor, i had implemented a method in Simperium that checked whether it needed to start, and if not was calling the logout and remove data method, doh!

Apologies, stupid friday question . . .

Thanks

Gareth